# Is there a way to set 'not null' for all params of @AllArgsConstructor (lombok)

Tags: java, lombok

I'm using the `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation in my class and want to be sure that arguments will be not null.
Is there a way to modify this annotation to make this possible, or I should implement constractor?
Thanks

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

}
```

...

```
<lombok.version>1.16.18</lombok.version>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you have to use `@ NonNull` on such fields, it will result in a null check in the generated constructor.

Comment: Thanks. Just one question: I annotated both fields with @NotNull. When I create and object like this Contact rob = new Contact(null, null); I get NullPointerException. But when I create an object like this Contact bill = new Contact("Bill", null); (with only phoneNumber = null) it is fine. No exceptions . Why?

Comment: @IKo Are you sure you got the right annotation? The lombok annotation is  `@NonNull`, not `@NotNull`.

Comment: @MichaelA.Schaffrath you are right. For one of the fields I accidentally put `@NotNull` Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@RequiredArgsConstructor

Generates a constructor with required arguments. Required arguments are final fields and fields with constraints such as @NonNull.
Complete documentation is found at the project lombok features page for @Constructor .
Even though it is not listed, this annotation also has the onConstructor parameter. See the full documentation for more details.

Comment: "Required arguments are final fields and fields with constraints such as @NonNull."  I don't see anything here regarding generation of non null checks? https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: If you look at decompiled .class file you find that `@RequiredArgsConstructor` does generate null checks for fields annotated with `@NonNull`. You can also read about it in docs: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor " All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as @NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared. For those fields marked with @NonNull, an explicit null check is also generated. The constructor will throw a NullPointerException if any of the parameters intended for the fields marked with @NonNull contain null."